# Is WordPress classical and block editor(s) too inefficient to handle large data?

Tags: editor

Recently I started using WordPress classical editor in order to insert or edit my data into the website. It is almost working fine except for copying or working with large data.

Whenever I want to perform the task of copying large data, say thousand's of lines of text then the editor becomes too slow and I am not allowed to edit further. When I try to copy the same data into a [Notepad](https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/notepad.html) or on some other websites such as google docs, it is going well. So the issue is only with the block or classical WordPress editor. It is becoming very difficult if I need to add a large data and edit it afterward.

The editor shows auto-saving and the browser page is not responsive

[image]

[image]

Is it due to the inherent nature of the WordPress classical/block editor or is there any reason  I am unaware while using the WordPress classical editor?

If such behavior is inherent to the  WordPress classical editor then is there any option for me to use the faster version of WordPress classical editor?

Comment: I guess that's TinyMCE behaviour, which is the library that WordPress uses for the classical editor. It's probably processing the text to or from HTML for the copy-paste - it might be possible to turn this off so it just gives you the raw content (if that works for you?) but I don't know if / how you'd do that. I haven't heard of a faster version of it though - what did you mean?

Comment: That first screenshot does not appear to be from the classic editor.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the text or a character count?  Also, is your site running any plugins or custom theme code?

Comment: @JacobPeattie But, it is the classical editor for editing my page on the website. How to check for it?

Comment: @LinneaHuxford 12thousand lines of code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The link of editor looks like `http:/<website_name.com>/wp-admin/post.php?post=<number>&action=edit`

Comment: @hanugm The classic editor doesn't have a different URL. Unless you're using the Classic Editor plugin you are using the Block Editor. If you install the Classic Editor plugin does that editor work better?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I installed and tried. It is also not working better. Can you guide me any other editor that works better?

Comment: I do not. Others might, but this is not really the place for recommendations, as such questions are off topic.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a page builder has taken over your Classic / Block Editor.  What theme are you using and what plugins has it installed?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Theme is provided by block editor itself.  
Highlighting Code Block, Hostinger, LiteSpeed Cache, Starter Templates, SyntaxHighlighter Evolved are the only plugins I am using currently. Please tell me if any are redundant.

Comment: @hanugm I'm not sure what an answer to this would look like. This isn't a discussion forum and you need to ask a specific question that someone can answer factually and be marked as the answer for all people with this question. To me this looks like a user support discussion, not a technical question

Comment: also, try it without the plugins, syntax highlighting is expensive, and you'll need to contact their support if you're having performance issues with their blocks

Comment: Theme provided by the block editor itself doesn't make any sense.  The block editor doesn't provide the them for your site.  If you're using something called 'Starter Templates' my guess is you have a 'Page Builder' on your site and will need to open a ticket with them.